# How to display summarised data as a text

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, reporting, custom-reports

I have a summary report on the User Presence object, it displays status duration at the summary level. the duration is in seconds and I need to display this in HH: MM: SS format.

The problem I'm facing is Summary level formula fields can't be Text, without text I can't display the Sum Of Status duration in HH: MM: SS format.

In the below-attached image, the highlighted sum I need to display in HH: MM: SS format.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you create those formula fields on Object and then use it in Summary report.

Comment: Even in objects formula it will be text and can’t summarised

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in my developer org. I extracted the Hours, Minutes and seconds using formula and then prefixed it with `NOW()` to get the Date time value. And then I extracted the Time Value. Below are the details steps:

1. Create a formula field of Time data type.
2. Put the formula as below:
   `TIMEVALUE( DATETIMEVALUE(NOW() + FLOOR(light002__number__c /3600) + FLOOR(MOD(light002__number__c ,3600)/60) + MOD(MOD(light002__number__c ,3600),60)))`
3. Use this formula
   field in your report to create a grouping.

I did above steps and was able to summarize the report based on time. Below is the snapshot:

[image]

Comment: What I’m looking is showing total duration in hours format instead of second. If my total duration is 24767 in seconds then I want it to be displayed as 6:87 hours

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper The seconds are only displayed in backend. If you look at the snapshot it shows the time in HH:MM format. You can refer this documentation to get the output as per your format: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5

Comment: I see what you are referring but what I’m expecting is total time so if I’m seeing one week data then the sum of all seconds can be more than 24 hrs like 40 hours

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper That will require some more modification in the formula. Refer this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds/. What I can observe is that hours, minutes and seconds remain unchanged. Take a look at that post.

Comment: I already have the formula to convert it in HH: MM format but it's in text format and text data type is not supported at a summarized level